# What was Kyouji's plan before he triggered the security in the Summoner Test System?

Tags: baka-and-test

At the beginning of season 1 episode 8 *"Runaway, Mazes, and the Summoned Beast Instrumentality Project"*, Kyouji was seen attempting to access the main system. When he was picked up by the security systems, he ran away, where he tripped over a cable and disconnected it, causing the entire system to go berserk.

Kyouji is known for his underhanded tactics and cheating, so it's obvious that he was trying to gain an unfair advantage over everyone else when he was trying to access the main system. What did he hope to do if he had gained access?

Comment: Changing the grades?